# how to convert php codes to vb.net for loop

Tags: php, .net

how do i convert this php code to vb
im trying to do this in .net but the value is only 1 value 
what is the code of .net using my php codes

this is my code in php

```
              $ctr = 7 
              for ($i = 0;$i < $ctr;$i++) 
                { 
                    $prenum .= '0';
                }
```

output = 0000000

```
    Dim prenum as string = "0"
    Dim ctr as Integer = 7
    For i = 0 To ctr
        output = prenum
    Next
```

output = 0

Comment: In your VB-code, you're not concatenating the string, you're replacing it. Read about concatenating in VB: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2585xw.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the operator '.' in php concatenates strings, the operator for vb to concatenate is '&'...

```
Dim prenum as string = "0"
Dim ctr as Integer = 7
For i = 0 To ctr
    output = output & prenum
Next
```

Comment: thanks i forgot that im trying the codes premun & premun btw thnx